# Prevent duplicate entry for unique constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, unique

I am trying to save tags which are related to an article in my MySQL database. The relation between those two columns is 1:N. Each item has an auto generated key. The name of a tag is unique.

If I insert a new article with an existing tag, I get a duplicate entry exception for the unique constraint (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException). This are my two entities:

*Article.java*

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();

    /* getter and setter */
}
```

*Tag.java*

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    /* getter and setter */
}
```

Hibernate generate following **tables**: **article**, **tag**, **article_tag**. For the first article the records are correct.

I use following code to insert a new article (only for testing):

```
Article article = new Article();
Tag tag = new Tag();
/* set the values */
EntityManager em = EMF.getInstance().get();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(article);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

How could I get JPA to use the existing tag for the article instead of create a new one. How do I set the relation between those so components correctly?

Comment: I'm assuming `The name of a tag is unique.` means that in the table containing the articles and tags the tags column is marked as unique, this effectively means that if you try to insert a different article with a tag that another article already has will throw your exception. The solution for this would be to have tags stored in a separate table where they are unique and then just insert references to the various tags in the article table via a foreign key. **TL;DR** *don't include `Tag`s in `Article`s, insead include references that can be mapped to `Tag`s*

Comment: Exactly, I am doing this. I have a third column `article_tag`, which contain the `Id` of the article and the tag. Each, article and tag are stored in a own table.

Comment: Try to change the `HashSet` object to contain `long`s representing the `Tag` IDs instead. Afterwards when you need to check the tags for an `Article` you retrieve the `long` stored in the `Article` record and then lookup the `Tag` table to match a tag with the ID you got from the `Article` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the relationship between articles and tags is a **many-to-many** relationship as an article may have **many** tags and each of these tags may be reused in **many** articles.

To indicate a **many-to-many** relationship the **@ManyToMany** annotation is required.

Also to make something clear, in the OP it is indicated a **unidirectionaly**  **one-to-many** relationship as the **@JoinTable** annotation has been used on the many side. This is the reason a join table has been created. In addition as a consequence if a **@ManyToOne** annotation is used in `Tag` class the **many-to-one** will be another **unidirectional** relationship. *Just be careful there as they will be handled as two independent unidirectional relationship with probable strange behaviour and any configuration will not affect both entities, since it is not a biderictional relationship.*

Finally, if it is required to have a **one-to-many** unidirectional relationship but also reuse the tags, it is required to retrieve them based on their name, so that they have the correct record id and then set the to the `Article` instance. If you try to set a new instance of `Tag` which will have no record id but a name that already exists, then the jpa provider will try to insert the new tag and a unique constraint exception will be thrown, because of the duplicate tag name. Also will need to remove any unique constraint referred to `tag_id` in `article_tag` table.

Comment: Is the unique constraint applicable to `@ManyToMany`?

Comment: @hofmeister if you are talking about `Tag` table yes as is in the post you provided, there should be a unique constraint for tag name. But in the `join table`  `article_tag` regarding `tag_id` no, there should not be a unique constraint for that in both cases since the tag side is `many` whether many-to-many or unidirectional one-to-many and the tag id will be associated many times, thus the same id may be present in multiple records.

Comment: Hm. Sorry, but I still do not know, how to connect entities with unique values with other entites. I tried @ManyToMany with mappedBy, but still get the unique exception.

Comment: @hofmeister maybe i was a bit confusing, whether you use `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany`, it is required to first retrieve the tag you want to associate from the db, using jpa, and then set that to the article. The tag instance needs to have the correct record id in order for jpa to associate it with an existing managed entity, otherwise it will try to insert a new record in tag table with the same tag name and the exception will be thrown.